# Where is Menu populating from?

Tags: php, css, sql, menu, content-management-system

I've been working on a site, built by someone else, at this point I am unable to find where I need to edit the menu.
http://mccorp.com/index is the site. Below is the navigation.php file that is calling the menu. None of the files called by loader.php have any menu information. The final goal is to move two of the sub-menu items under a different one and delete the one they were moved from. I feel like it is populating the menu from the database but the database pages table has nothing but the pages and I don't know what I might need to edit to change their order and location, none of the parent_pageid's correspond with their actual order or placement. The page_id's do not dictate order or location either. And index1.php referenced below doesn't even exist. I have tried to provide all the information needed to help, but I haven't let me know and I will update. I appreciate the time...

```
    <?php 
    include('include/loader.php'); 

    //if($current_filename=="index") {
    //  $parent_query="SELECT page_id, page_name, page_title, parent_pageid, seo_url FROM tbl_pages WHERE is_delete='0' and is_active='0'";
    //}
    $where ="";
    if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])=="index.php" || basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])=="index1.php") {
        $where = " and page_id not in ('35','36','37','58')";
    }
    $parent_query="SELECT page_id, page_name, page_title, parent_pageid, seo_url FROM tbl_pages WHERE is_delete='0' and is_active='0' ".$where ." order by rank desc";
    $menus_results=$sqlobj->getdatalistfromquery($parent_query);

    $arr_menuslist = $arr_menuslist_temp = $arr_submenuslist_temp = array();
    if(count($menus_results)>0) {
        foreach($menus_results as $key=>$value) {
            $arr_menuslist_temp[$value["parent_pageid"]][] = $value;
        }
    } 
    if(count($arr_menuslist_temp)>0) {
        $arr_menuslist = $arr_menuslist_temp[0];
        foreach($arr_menuslist as $key=>$value) {
            $arr_sub_menu = $arr_menuslist_temp[$value["page_id"]];
            if(count($arr_sub_menu)>0) {
                foreach($arr_sub_menu as $subkey=>$subvalue) {
                    $arr_sub_menu[$subkey]["submenu"] = $arr_menuslist_temp[$subvalue["page_id"]];

                    $arr_sublevel_menu = $arr_menuslist_temp[$subvalue["page_id"]];
                    if(count($arr_sublevel_menu)>0) {
                        foreach($arr_sublevel_menu as $sub_level_key=>$sub_level_value) {
                            $arr_sub_menu[$subkey]["submenu"][$sub_level_key]["sublevel"] = $arr_menuslist_temp[$sub_level_value["page_id"]];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            $arr_menuslist[$key]["mainmenu"] = $arr_sub_menu;
        }
    }
?>
<?php if(count($arr_menuslist)>0) {
    $arr_menus_result = $arr_menuslist[0]["mainmenu"];
    foreach($arr_menus_result as $key=>$value) {
    ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $value['seo_url']; ?>"><?php echo $value['page_name']; ?></a>
        <?php if(count($value["submenu"])>0) { ?>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach($value["submenu"] as $subkey=>$subvalue) {  ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $subvalue['seo_url']; ?>"><?php echo $subvalue['page_name']; ?></a>
                    <?php if(count($subvalue["sublevel"])>0) { ?>
                    <ul>
                        <?php foreach($subvalue["sublevel"] as $sublevelkey=>$sublevelvalue) {  ?>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo $sublevelvalue['seo_url']; ?>"><?php echo $sublevelvalue['page_name']; ?></a></li>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </ul>
                    <?php } ?>
            </li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
        <?php } ?>
    </li>
    <?php } } ?>
```

Comment: It seems your menu consist of pages. In your database your pages have parent_ids, these make up the (sub)menu_items. If there is no cms you could change those values in the database directly. Do backup before making changes.

Comment: This worked. I changed the parent_pageid setting and it moved the item as nice as you please. Such an obvious and simple fix in hindsight. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There might be options or configurations for "mainmenu" in the CMS.

What is the CMS?

Answer (score 0):

Editing the parent_pageide property directly in the database re-associated the menu items. Thank you RST for the suggestions.